# Analytic Combinatorics: upper bound for sum of absolute values of two complex functions: $|z f'(z)| + |2 f(z) - zf'(z)| \leq 2f(|z|)$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, inequalities, enumerative-combinatorics

Let $f \colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be a complex-valued analytic function with non-negative coefficients of Taylor series at 0 (suppose that radius of convergence is $+\infty$ for simplicity):
$$
   f(z) = c_0 + c_1 z + c_2 z^2 + \ldots \enspace ,
$$
$c_k \geq 0$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$, and also $c_1 > 0$.

It is well-known that for such functions their characteristic function $\phi_0(z) = \dfrac{z f'(z)}{f(z)}$ is nondecreasing when $z \in \mathbb R_+$. We also introduce characteristic function of the derivative $\phi_1(z) = \dfrac{z f''(z)}{f'(z)}$ which is also nondecreasing when $z \in \mathbb R_+$. So, there exists unique real positive solution $\widehat z$ of the equation $\phi_1(\widehat z) = 1$, since $c_1 > 0$ and $\phi_1(0) = 0$, under some mild conditions (there should be at least one nonzero coefficient among $c_3, c_4, \ldots$).

**Conjecture.** If $0 < |z| < \widehat z$, then it holds
$$
    |\phi_0(z)| + |2 - \phi_0(z)| \leq 2 \dfrac{f(|z|)}{|f(z)|} \enspace .
$$
Moreover, if the function $f(z)$ is aperiodic in the sense
$$
    \mathrm{GCD}\{i - j \colon c_i \neq 0, \, c_j \neq 0\} = 1
$$
then equality holds only iff $z$ is a real positive, i.e. $z = |z|$.

**Hints.** I should mention some of my previous attempts on this conjecture. It is important to mention that if $z = |z| < \widehat z$ then $\phi_0(z) \leq 2$. The equality is attained only for some degenerate functions $f(z)$. The sketch of the proof is following. The equation $\phi_1(\widehat z) = 1$ is equivalent to
$$
    c_1 = 3 c_3 z^2 + 8 c_4 z^3 + \ldots + (k-1)(k+1) c_{k+1}z^k + \ldots \enspace ,
$$
whereas the inequality $\phi_0(z) \leqslant 2$ is equivalent to
$$
    2 c_0 + c_1 z \geq c_3 z^3 + 2 c_4 z^4 + \ldots + (k-2) c_k z^k + \ldots \enspace ,
$$
which is true because all the coefficients are nonnegative, and $(k-1)(k+1) \geq k-2$.

Some obvious tricks with triangle inequalities didn't work in my case, because there is an obvious lower bound
$$
    2 \leq |\phi_0(z)| + |2 - \phi_0(z)| \enspace .
$$
I also tried to prove equivalent inequality
$$
    |z f'(z)| + |2 f(z) - z f'(z)| \leq 2 f(z_0) \enspace ,
$$
which seems easier, because of explicit representation for $2f(z) - zf'(z)$.
If we denote $z = z_0 e^{i \theta}$, then the function
$$
   \Phi(\theta) = |z f'(z)| + |2f(z) - zf'(z)|
$$
can have a plot with large number of local maxima and minima. I plot first summand (1), second summand (2) and lower bound $|2f(z)|$ (3). The sum (1+2) is also depicted. We can see that the behavior is "very tight".

[Picture: Separate summands of $\Phi(\theta)$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roXqS.png)

Every strategy I tried, didn't seem to give hopeful result, though I tried to simplify and consider particular cases like $f(z) = e^z$, $f(z) = \sinh z$. It is complicated to work with absolute value, since it is not analytic. The idea of $|\omega| = \sqrt{\omega \overline \omega}$ also didn't lead me to the solution, however maybe I was not patient enough to finish that, i mean consider square root of infinite sums. I also tried to simulate the inequality in `ipython` for many dfferent sequences, and it always turned out valid.

**Motivation**. This lemma is important in graph enumeration, because the conjecture leads to some saddle-point estimates for asymptotic number of graphs with certain structure. In particular, the generating function of graph with $n$ unrooted trees, after some transformation, takes the form $g(z)e^{nh(z)}$, and this is the contour integral we want to calculate. Usually, $\Re h(z)$ on a circle $z = z_0 e^{i\theta}$ has maximal value at $z = z_0$, i.e. $\theta = 0$.

Any helpful ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, it is true and follows from the following elementary

**Lemma.** If $\alpha>\beta>0$ and $1/\beta-1/\alpha\geqslant 2$, then $|1+\alpha z|+|1-\beta z|\leqslant 2+\alpha-\beta$ for any vector $z$ with $|z|=1$.

**Proof** of the lemma. Some nice argument must exist, but you may simply denote $z=e^{it}$ and differentiate LHS in $t$. For real $z$ the inequality is clear, else in a point where derivative equals 0 you get $\alpha/|1+\alpha z|=\beta/|1-\beta z|$, $|z+1/\alpha|=|z-1/\beta|$, but perpendicular bisector to the segment $[-1/\alpha,1/\beta]$ does not contain non-real points of a unit circle provided that $1/\beta-1/\alpha\geqslant 2$.

Now we have $c_1\geqslant \sum_{k\geqslant 2} (k^2-1)c_{k+1}|z|^k$ and need to prove 
$$
|c_1z+2c_2z^2+3c_3z^3+\dots |+|2c_0+c_1z-c_3z^3-2c_4z^4-\dots|\leqslant\\ 2c_0+2c_1|z|+2c_2|z|^2+\dots,
$$
for proving that at first we use triangle inequality for removing terms with $c_0$ and $c_2$, then divide by $|z|$, we reduce our inequality to
$$
|c_1+3c_3z^2+\dots |+|c_1-c_3z^2-2c_4z^3-\dots|\leqslant 2c_1+2c_3|z|^2+\dots,
$$
set $c_1=a+3c_3|z|^2+8c_4|z|^3+\dots$ for some non-negative $a$ and use triangle inequality many times, we reduce the inequality to a family of inequalities $$|(k^2-1)|z|^k+(k+1)z^k|+|(k^2-1)|z|^k-(k-1)z^k|\leqslant (2(k^2-1)+2)|z|^k$$
(this inequality goes with coefficient $c_{k+1}$), but this is a partial case of lemma with $\alpha=1/(k-1),\beta=1/(k+1)$.

Comment: That's amazing, thank you for the proof! I understand now your idea of pulling the terms from the triangle inequality: I couldn't guess to push the condition $\phi_1(|z|) \leq 1$ in terms of coefficient $c_1 \geq \ldots$, now it is clear. As for the lemma, I also couldn't come with the idea of how to bound the sum of two absolute values. It is still non-obvious to me, in geometrical sense (I tried to re-prove it using inversion but also didn't succeed). Would be nice if you explain how did you guess the lemma :)

Comment: Partial case of the lemma arises when $f$ has only two non-zero coefficients, say $c_1 z+c_5 z^5$. So it arises naturally (of course, I did not know a priori what are necessary conditions for $\alpha,\beta$, it is a luck that they are exactly what we are given. But probably not just a luck.)